# Responsive background image (full height)

Tags: css, responsive-design, background-image

I want to put an image as background in a website and I want that image to be responsive but the footer is always the bottom, so that the image resized addition, I would like to be "cut off" in width. I give you three examples.

Example # 1: Viewing the web in a 16:9

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5xDd.jpg

Example # 2: Viewing the web on a smartphone

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdlPV.jpg

Can anyone help me? (I use google translate so forgive any odd English usage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
background-size: cover;
```

or

```
background-size: contain;
```